# Request only content from current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a service that does a request,

```
.factory('movieService', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    loadMovies: function() {
      return $http.get('/movies_users.json');
    }
  };
}])
```

This is the JSON output and is the result of 2 tables being joined. A user table and a movie table. As you can see the users are associated with 1 or more movies.

```
[
  {"id":1,
  "email":"peter@peter.nl",
    "movies":[
      {
        "id":4,
        "title":"Creed",
        movie_id":"312221"
      },
      {
      "id":5,
        "title":"Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens",
        "movie_id":"140607"
      }
    ]
  },

  {"id":2,
  "email":"jan@jan.com",
    "movies":[
      {
        "id":4,
        "title":"Creed",
        movie_id":"312221"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And this is the `movies_users_controller.rb`

```
def index
  movie = Movie.all
  render :json => movie.to_json(:include => :users)
end
```

Is it possible to only show the current user in the JSON output instead of both users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to only show the current user in the JSON output
>   instead of both users?

That implies that you have some authentication system (if you don't, you can have a look at [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)).

Instead of fetching all the movies, just get the movies of the current user.

```
 @movies = current_user.movies
```

In order to make this work, you'll have to have a relationship between the User model and the Movie model, something like this:

```
 # user.rb
 has_many :user_movies
 has_many :movies, through: user_movies

 # user_movie.rb
 belongs_to :movie
 belongs_to :user

 # movie.rb
 has_many :user_movies
 has_many :users, through: :user_movies
```

Also, it seems that you are building an API, I would advice to use something like jbuilder to build your json object, it will be cleaner and you will be able to display pretty much everything you want.

Comment: `movie = current_user.movies
    render :json => movie.to_json()`

Using this in my movies_users controller creates a json output with only the information from the current user!

Comment: What do you mean? The informations of the user itself?

Comment: Now when I visit localhost:3000/movies_users.json I only see the movies from the current user (which I was looking for!)

Comment: Yeah, isn't it what you wanted?

Comment: Yes it is! That's what I'm saying ;)